# XmlTextAttribute equivalent in DataContracts

Tags: .net, datacontractserializer

Is there an equivalent to XmlTextAttribute when using DataContractSerializer?

I want to treate a property as the 'default property when it is serialized to XML. For example:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

A object with .Value set to "foo" is serialized as:

```
<Item>foo</Item>
```

rather than:

```
<Item><Value>foo</Value></Item>
```

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that using the DataContractSerializer.

Marc